# Should I use classes for individual factions in simple strategy game - C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have decided to challenge myself into creating a simple Risk-type strategy game in C++. The game will have multiple factions fighting for control of territories using various types of troop/unit.

I am only in the basic outlining of the game, but one basic idea I have is to create a class for each faction:

```
class Windows {
private:
    bool isWindows = true;
    // Characteristics etc.
};

class Mac {
private:
    bool isMac = true;
    // Characteristics etc.
};

class Linux {
private:
    bool isLinux = true;
    // Characteristics etc.
};
```

After which individual classes of unit will inherit certain characteristics of the faction which it is associated, such as: `class Penguin: private Linux {//Code};`

Is this the best way of doing this, or is there a better way with fewer classes?

Comment: Are the different factions all fundamentally the same thing with different identies, or do they work in different ways? Do they all have the same kinds of units?

Comment: My idea was that each faction has a specific advantage, like more resources or stronger units. For now, each faction has the same types of units.

Comment: class Faction defines how they work, which is basically the same. Normally, each faction would be a simple instance of the class Faction, and you can give them stat tweaks by changing variables. But if you are going to build fundamentally different factions, it will be better to subclass, and just inherit the basic behavior of Faction.

Comment: Sounds more like a single class `Faction` with each faction having different properties.

Comment: Unless a given unit can be e.g. both Windows *and* Mac at the same time, then setting a separate boolean for each of those is overkill -- if you want to tag each unit for quick identification of its faction, use a base class and put something like `enum {Windows, Mac, Linux};   int myFaction = Mac;` instead.  That way you implicitly guarantee that a given unit can only be identified with one faction at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the different factions have different settings for the same set of characteristics which suggests that you should have one `Faction` class and have different instances of `Faction`.

I assume you need only one instance of each faction. They can be a kind of singleton. The idiomatic way of doing singletons in c++ is using a function returning a reference to a local static variable:

```
class Faction {
    // Characteristics etc.
};

const Faction& windows() {
  static Faction f{ /* initialize with windows characteristics */ };
  return f;
}

const Faction& mac() {
  static Faction f{ /* initialize with mac characteristics */ };
  return f;
}

const Faction& linux() {
  static Faction f{ /* initialize with linux characteristics */ };
  return f;
}
```

Then a class like `Penguin`, rather than inheriting from a `Faction` can use the linux instance of `Faction`. It could, for example, hold a reference to its faction:

```
class Penguin {
    const Faction& faction = linux();
public:
    void someAction() {
        // use faction reference
    }
};
```

I suggest you try to avoid checks like "isLinux" as it makes code brittle and instead rely on characteristics of the faction object itself. The less code that has to change if you introduce a new faction the better. If you really do need to detect the type of a faction then because the faction instances are singleton you can compare the address:

```
bool isWindows(const Faction& f) { return &f == &windows(); }
bool isLinux(const Faction& f) { return &f == &linux(); }
bool isMac(const Faction& f) { return &f == &mac(); }
```

If you do this it is probably a good idea to prevent a `Faction` object from being copied so you can rely on it being at the right address:

```
class Faction {
    // ...

    // uncopyable
    Faction(const Faction&) = delete;
    Faction& operator=(const Faction&) = delete;
 };
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O7iEmVnir9tUOb2a).

Answer (score 2):

If factions have similarities use a base class and them make individual subclasses for each faction and faction class as base class for units.